# what does JAXB mean?

Tags: java, jaxb

Any meaning for JAXB? Just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) allows Java developers to map Java classes to XML representations. JAXB provides two main features: the ability to marshal Java objects into XML and the inverse, i.e. to unmarshal XML back into Java objects.

In other words, JAXB allows storing and retrieving data in memory in any XML format, without the need to implement a specific set of XML loading and saving routines for the program's class structure. It is similar to xsd.exe and xmlserializers in .Net Framework.

JAXB is particularly useful when the specification is complex and changing. In such a case, regularly changing the XML Schema definitions to keep them synchronised with the Java definitions can be time consuming and error prone.

JAXB is a part of Java SE platform and one of the APIs in the Java EE platform, and is part of the Java Web Services Development Pack (JWSDP). It is also one of the foundations for WSIT. JAXB is part of SE version 1.6.

Comment: +1 - JAXB is the JSR-222 spec (http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jaxb-xml-binding-standard.html).  In addition to the reference implementation you mentioned there are others including:  EclipseLink JAXB (MOxy) and Apache JaxMe.

Comment: Seems content is copied from below wikipedia link. No Effort is being put in to improve content. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding

Why don't you use google before asking?

Comment: I saw some book use JAX-B, I thought it is JA-XB, is there any other JAX-?

Comment: There are many JAX-? specs: JAXP (parsing), JAX-WS (XML Web Service), JAX-RS (RESTful Service), JAXM (XML messaging), etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Architecture for XML binding](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)

Unmarshalling an XML document converts it to a Java object, while marshalling a Java object creates an XML document.  Of course, a binding between the XML schema and a class/interface needs to also be present.

Comment: That article is quite old and covers JAXB 1.  For JAXB 2 see http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html
JAXB stands for java architecture for XML binding

Comment: That article is quite old and covers JAXB 1.  For JAXB 2 see http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222